# Which IPs are possible when using Virtual IP (VIP)

Tags: google-app-engine

We are using App Engine with a Custom Domain and SSL with Virtual IP. The GAE documentation says that we must use CNAME because the IP may change.

One of our customer wants to set up a firewall rule so our service is available without proxy. Therefore we need an IP or IP range that will be allowed.

Which are the possible IPs when using Virtual IP? How often such an IP will change?